# Saving the output file from airodump-ng in Python using pyrcrack

Tags: python, packet-sniffers

Is it possible to save .cap file using pyrcrack (same as airodump-ng -w output wlan)? Didn't catch it in the official documentation.
Any help will be appriciated! Thanks!

I can save it using command line, but I would like to do it in background

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.